# Excluding files from being considered text in .gitattributes

Tags: git, gitattributes

I see a lot of repositories with `.gitattributes` files that normalise line endings with content like below:

```
*.js text eol=lf
```

Which should only normalise `.js` text files, but they also explicitly exclude some binary files such as `.png` files:

```
*.png -text
```

This doesn't seem necessary as the first rule is only  applied to text-based `.js` files. Is this correct? Or is this just considered best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what your question is.  The question I will answer is this: *Is it necessary or advisable to mark particular files as text or binary, in `.gitattributes`, when directing Git to perform CRLF line ending conversion?*

The answer is: *It is not **necessary** but it is **advisable**.*  In the absence of explicit advice, Git will *guess*, based on file contents (not file names or extensions, but a simple statistical analysis of byte-by-byte contents).  Will Git guess that your jpg image is text, and thereby corrupt it?  Will Git guess that your program source is binary, and therefore not bother to do CRLF line ending tweaking?  I don't know, and neither do you.

Git's guesses are pretty darn good.  But why take the risk, when listing your files explicitly is easy, and completely removes this risk?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @torek! Sorry that my question doesn't make more sense. I can try and explain it better. Basically because I'm applying the LF line endings setting to `.js` files, I'm assuming it will not apply to other formats so why would I need to explicitly state not to treat them as text files? If the only rule I have only applies to one format which will always be a text file in my repo.

Comment: Git has several different *ways* for you to ask that it muck with line endings. One of them is this `.gitattributes` method, which is explicit based on file names and/or glob patterns. The other one—which people do use—is "if I didn't say in .gitattributes, please guess". (I recommend that people not turn this option on in general, myself, and if they don't, you're right: not listing the file is the same as listing it as "don't touch". But I find that people who list files at all, also turn on the global option.)

Comment: I presume this is the option that's configured in the Git installer with the three options that set `core.autocrlf`?

Comment: Yes: if you turn on `core.autocrlf`, Git starts guessing—and now you (or at least I) would really want an explicit setting for every file. Of course, if you have an explicit setting for every file, there's no point in setting `core.autocrlf` to `true`, is there? :-) What might be nice is if Git had a scan program that would tell you: "hey, this particular file doesn't have a gitattributes setting"...

Comment: Interesting... Seems like most users will accept the default setting. The default option is "Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings".  Would committing the files under this setting not revert the corruption as it is converting the files back into LF format from CRLF when it was checked out?

Comment: Imagine a file is a JPG image.  The JPG image happens to have two bytes in a row, 13 (decimal) and then 10 (decimal), in the actual image. Suppose Git decides that the file is text (possible, though not likely). Git says: aha, here'a CRLF line ending! I will strip out the CR and store just the LF-only line ending. Later, in the same binary file, there's a byte 10 (only). Git says: aha, here's a bare LF, I will store LF (only) as the line ending. Checking out the file later, Git turns the first one into CRLF (good) and the second into CRLF (bad).

Comment: We discover the corrupted image. Aha, we say, Git just needs to be told that this image is binary. We mark it as such (in `.gitattributes`) and force Git to re-extract it as binary. This time, Git leaves the two lone LFs as LFs. The image is now corrupt, differently. Oops!

Comment: In CS-theoretic terms, what we have is a non-invertible mapping. Some translations are invertible and some are not. Which one we get, for any given binary file, is luck. If we would like to have a reliable computing system, we should not rely on luck... By marking the file as binary, we tell Git: do not do any mapping. With no mapping, there's no risk of a non-invertible mapping.

Comment: That's a good explaination. That cleared it up for me. Thanks @torek!